# -[announceViewController xCJSONDidBeginLoadingJSONData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa01504d50

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have got this problem cause the app crash:
The probelm start when the app launch when I add the new view to handle 2 uiimages with two buttons

```
    gameApp[5963:1756169] -[announceViewController xCJSONDidBeginLoadingJSONData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa01504d50
2014-11-03 09:16:01.386 gameApp[5963:1756169] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[announceViewController xCJSONDidBeginLoadingJSONData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa01504d50'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107fe9f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107c82bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107ff104d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f4908f ___forwarding___ + 495
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f48e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   gameApp                             0x0000000103d75462 -[XCJSONLoader startLoadFrom:] + 66
    6   gameApp                             0x0000000103d75de3 -[announceViewController setUpJSON] + 259
    7   gameApp                             0x0000000103d75c99 -[announceViewController viewDidLoad] + 73
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000106402a90 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000106402c8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000106321ca9 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000106322041 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010632e72c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001062d9061 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2628
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001062dbd2c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001062dabf2 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010dfa62a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f1f53c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f15285 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f15045 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f14486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001062da669 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001062dd420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  gameApp                             0x0000000103d78913 main + 115
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108c17145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

and here is the h file :

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XCJSONLoader.h"

@interface announceViewController : UIViewController <XCJSONLoaderDelegate>
@property (strong,nonatomic) XCJSONLoader *jsonLoader;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *anImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *spImageView;
- (IBAction)anButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)spButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

and this is the .m file

```
@interface announceViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *JSONData;

}

@end

@implementation announceViewController

@synthesize jsonLoader,anImageView,spImageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self setUpJSON];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/


- (void) setUpJSON
{
    jsonLoader = [[XCJSONLoader alloc] init];

    [jsonLoader setDelegate:self];

    NSString *JSONLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ya-techno.com/gameApp/anData.php"]; // Your URL goes here


    [jsonLoader startLoadFrom:JSONLink];


}
- (void)xCJSONDidFinishLoadingJSONData
{
    JSONData = [jsonLoader getJSONData];


}



- (IBAction)anButton:(id)sender {
    JSONData = [jsonLoader getJSONData];

    NSString *anButtonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[JSONData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"anButton"]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:anButtonString]];



}

- (IBAction)spButton:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

I could not find the problem for this one. Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the error. It says you haven't implemented the `xCJSONDidBeginLoadingJSONData` method. And you haven't. You do have the `xCJSONDidFinishLoadingJSONData` method but not the `xCJSONDidBeginLoadingJSONData` method.

Add the `xCJSONDidBeginLoadingJSONData` method to your `announceViewController` class to fix the problem.

BTW - standard naming conventions state that class names should being with uppercase letters. Method and variable names begin with lowercase letters.